# Delete files with same md5sum in cshell

Tags: shell, duplicates, md5sum

I am trying to implement a check where all files with same md5sum will be deleted keeping the first occurrence.

Input: First column is of md5 values and 2nd is the file name.

```
ab331f253704b84ae0aa5606adce4e7d  1.tcl              
ab331f253704b84ae0aa5606adce4e7d  2.tcl             
d86bbfda16f0d63ba35945e09dddce4d  3.tcl            
1d0b140d16d32d2adbaa15643bdba412  4.tcl            
8c97ae7965ae44ca6a4000d4e5988d54  5.tcl             
ddf373efda3bbdf83d2dfa9cb7fc4d96  6.tcl                  
1d0b140d16d32d2adbaa15643bdba412  7.tcl               
ddf373efda3bbdf83d2dfa9cb7fc4d96  8.tcl
```

Output: Perform rm -rf 2.tcl 7.tcl 8.tcl since other files with same md5sum exist.

```
ab331f253704b84ae0aa5606adce4e7d  1.tcl             
d86bbfda16f0d63ba35945e09dddce4d  3.tcl               
1d0b140d16d32d2adbaa15643bdba412  4.tcl                           
8c97ae7965ae44ca6a4000d4e5988d54  5.tcl            
ddf373efda3bbdf83d2dfa9cb7fc4d96  6.tcl
```

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to delete lines from input, not actually delete the files, right? BTW: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that your goal is to delete certain lines from your textual input, not actually to delete the files.

Like this:

```
awk '! seen[$1]++'
```

This reads from standard input. If the input is in a file, you can do:

```
awk '! seen[$1]++' inputfile.txt
```

Or, if it's the output of some command:

```
some_command | awk '! seen[$1]++'
```

Explanation: `seen` is an associative array. `$1` is the first whitespace-delimited field of the current line. `awk` processes input line-by-line. `seen[$1]` tells you whether first field of the current line has been seen before; the `++` increments that value, marking the current line as already seen for the next time you see it. Incrementing a nonexistent array element sets it to `1`.

This assumes you have `awk` installed on your system. You probably do.

If you're looking for a solution in pure csh, without invoking an external command, that's going to be more difficult (and I can't think of a good reason to do that).

---

Apparently you actually want to delete the files. Here's a solution for that:

```
awk '{ md5sum = $1; file = $2; if (seen[md5sum]++) { print "rm", file } }'
```

Again, you'll need to provide the desired input to this command.

This prints, but does not execute, a series of `rm` commands.  For example, given the input in the question the output is:

```
rm 2.tcl
rm 7.tcl
rm 8.tcl
```

You could modify the `awk` command to use `system("rm " file")` rather than just printing it, but for added safety I'd write the output to a file, check that it looks correct, and then `source` the file to remove the files. It's easy to shoot yourself in the foot with a script that removes files automatically based on arbitrary input.

Comment: Thanks. I can access other utilities from inside the shell but the files need to be deleted.

Comment: @zerodb: As it stands, the question looks like you just want to generate the specified output text given the specified input text (and that's what I answered). If you actually want to do the equivalent of, in this case, `rm 1.tcl 7.tcl 8.tcl`, please update your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

What's your problem? the algorithm or implementing it in csh?

If you're not looking for blazing fast operations, the naive algorithm is straightforward:

In a pseudo-language:

```
for srcfile in sorted(list_of_files):
  for tgtfile in list_of_files:
    if srcfile != tgtfile and md5(srcfile) == md5(tgtfile):
      delete tgtfile
```